# Could not connect to ActiveMQ service running on AWS - EC2

Tags: java, tcp, amazon-ec2, activemq-classic

I am trying to connect to aws-ec2 instance having activemq service running. I am trying to connect it using tcp transport connector using an application built under java + maven + git setting.

I am doing this exercise to add network latency to compare activemq with aws-sqs, which will help us in deciding which one to use for our requirements.

what I have tried so far:

I am able to run this application locally as I scp'ed into ec2 added my code there and it ran locally, which led me to believe that amq service is running.

I also ran the same setting from my home network it is working fine, so home computer -> ec2 connection is also working.

It is just not working from my office network, which led me to believe that it is failing because of some kind of firewall setting?

A simple netstat -a | grep 61616 gave me that it is listening on port 61616.

Does anyone know where I am going wrong? Or suggest some more debugging techniques?

EDIT: Security rule at aws-ec2

[image]

Comment: Is the security group set up correctly? Some company networks also restrict outgoing traffic which might be causing an issue.

Comment: @datasage I have added the screenshot of the current security setting.

Comment: In which case your office network is probably blocking you. You will need to tunnel over a port that is not blocked, or ask your network admin to open the port for you.

Comment: I just changed the ports of service + console which is being allowed by work firewall. Thank once again @datastage